# how to add theme provider in next.js app?

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, themes, provider

i want to add themeprovider to my app so i can easily change between dark and light mode

this how my layout.tsx looks like:

```
import "./globals.css";
import "@/styles/nav.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import createApolloClient from "./apollo";
import Header from "./header";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { darkTheme } from "@/styles/ThemeConfig";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
const client = createApolloClient();

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
          <Header></Header>
          {children}
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

i'm getting error:
Server Error
Error: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component

if i'm adding use client to layout.tsx my page still dont work and i'm getting other error
Failed to compile
./src\app\layout.tsx
ReactServerComponentsError:

You are attempting to export "metadata" from a component marked with "use client", which is disallowed. Either remove the export, or the "use client" directive. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive

how to add theme provider?

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

export const lightTheme = {
  body: "#FFF",
  text: "#363537",
  toggleBorder: "#FFF",
  background: "#363537",
};

export const darkTheme = {
  body: "#363537",
  text: "#FAFAFA",
  toggleBorder: "#6B8096",
  background: "#999",
};

export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    background: ${({ theme }) => theme.body};
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.text};
    font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Roboto, sans-serif;
    transition: all 0.50s linear;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 7):

You are getting the error:

> Server Error Error: createContext only works in Client Components.
> Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more:
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component

because `ThemeProvider` is supposed to be run on client-side (meaning a client-component). All client components in Next.js need to be marked with `"use client"` directive.

Since your `ThemeProvider` component is from `styled-components`, that means you cannot mark it as `"use client"`.

---

The next option is to make `RootLayout` as a client component. But,

> The root layout is a Server Component by default and can not be set to a Client Component.
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts

So you cannot add `"use client"` to `src/app/layout.tsx` as well.

---

That means the only option is to create another component (which will be a client component) and you need to use `ThemeProvider` inside it. Then use this component in `RootLayout`.

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ThemeClient>
          <Header></Header>
          {children}
        </ThemeClient>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
"use client"

import { darkTheme } from "@/styles/ThemeConfig";

export default function ThemeClient({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: does this not cause all downstream components to become a client side component? im quoting the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components), `"use client" is used to declare a boundary between a Server and Client Component modules. This means that by defining a "use client" in a file, all other modules imported into it, including child components, are considered part of the client bundle.`